# What causes NormalizeServiceUrl and Missing or Invalid property errors when attempting to publish a website from VS 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, web, publish

I (and others on my team) have published this project via VS2012 in the past, but something must have changed and I don't know what to look for.

To clarify I can publish other projects, but this one gives me 2 errors after building successfully.

1. Error   7   The "NormalizeServiceUrl" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ServiceUrl".       0   0   ProjectName
2. Error   6   Web Deploy publish/package validating error: Missing or Invalid property value for $(MsDeployServiceUrl)        0   0   ProjectName

I have deleted and re-created the PublishProfile and it still happens. It also happens on everyone else's machine that tries to publish this project (right click project > Publish > select Web Deploy > click Publish). We have published this before and the website is still running, we just can't update it now since Publish won't work. Also, I validated the Connection in case you were going to ask.

I don't know what was changed since we last deployed in July.
So, what can I do to solve these errors and successfully publish?

Comment: Is this running on Azure Web Sites, or Azure Cloud Services?

Comment: Nope, no Azure in this project at all. Unfortunately, most results when I was Googling this issue were related to Azure. So, I ended up posting the question here, in case anyone has had and solved this for a regular .NET 4 cshtml type Website. And if I find a solution then hopefully it will be seen by anyone else not using Azure and looking for a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you solve the problem or find a workaround? I'm struggling with the same issue right now, but using VS 2013 Update 4.

Comment: Well, we are also using VS 2013 now, but I haven't tried in a while. Now we actually have a script in TeamCity to push the files to the appropriate server after each build & transform. Also this was a project that doesn't really get updated. So, I'm sorry, but I never found a VS solution.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30983586/26226

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's no more a problem but in the last days i've got my head banging on this issue. I've opened up the .csproj and i found i got this line duplicated

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

so after removing the line from the project i've cleaned up *.user files and all worked like a charm.

And yes you ha e to' reload the project

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an asp.net project for vs.net 2010 that I used in vs.net 2019. I resolved it by changing the target framework from 4.0 to 4.5 in projects properties settings.