# Visual Studio Web Deploy Error - "NormalizeServiceUrl"

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am setting up a new dev server, and moving some old projects to this.  I opened up one of the older web projects.  Setup the publish settings to use Web Deploy just like I have done for many projects.  However, on this one I am getting the following error when clicking the preview.

> Error 3   The "NormalizeServiceUrl" task was not given a value for the
>   required parameter "ServiceUrl".

If I try to publish with out preview, I get an additional error.

> Web Deploy publish/package validating error: Missing or Invalid
>   property value for $(MsDeployServiceUrl)

I have looked all over and cant find help on the "NormalizeServiceUrl" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post about a similar problem.  This led me to open the vbproj file.  I looked at a project of ours that looked fine.

It had these 3 lines in the vbproj file.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />  
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

My project with the issue only had

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

I added the other 2 lines and this issue was resolved.  I hope this helps anyone that comes across this.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this error in Visual Studio 2013. It looks like the project wasn't upgraded properly from VS 2010. I changed this line:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

To (v10.0 => v12.0):

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of incorrect import for VS 2019,
project line to fix:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

fixed

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```